# Renaming object R in customised way

Tags: r

Suppose, I have a object in R named test.
let,

```
> x<-c('a','b','c')
> x[1]
[1] "a"
```

now I want to rename object test as 'a'. So i tried

```
> a[1]<-reg_gcm_ind
Warning message:
In a[1] <- reg_gcm_ind :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

so, I'm unable to rename test as 'a'. How can I do this?

Comment: Where is "test" and what is "reg_gcm_ind"? It's unclear as it stands.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `assign` function, but your code has `x` and `reg_gcm_ind` but your description has "test" and "a", so you your example is very not clear.

Comment: .. and what is `a[1]`?  This post is asking for others to assume a lot...

Comment: Javed, please edit your question to address the comments above. Otherwise it may be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: assign function has done my job.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect reg_gcm_ind, which you've included no information about, is not a scalar or length 1 vector

```
> x<-c('a','b','c')
> x[1]
[1] "a"
> x[1] <- "something else"
> x
[1] "something else" "b"              "c"
```